# bash script environment/result ambiguity

Tags: bash, shell-script, arch-linux, wpa-cli

I'm running Arch Linux with i3wm.

```
$ uname -a
Linux lappie 5.3.1-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Sep 21 11:33:49 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ i3 --version
i3 version 4.17.1 (2019-08-30) © 2009 Michael Stapelberg and contributors
```

I have this scriptfile `function.sh` that scans the wifi with `wpa_cli`. It checks the return of `> scan` and returns the results if the scan was successful.

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile=/$HOME/.logfile

echo "function" >> $logfile
echo "" >> $logfile

interface="wlp2s0"

function scan_wifi {


    scan=$(sudo wpa_cli -i $interface scan)
    echo "scan: $scan" >> $logfile

        case "$scan" in
        "OK")
            echo "Scanning wifi" >> $logfile
            scan_res=$(sudo wpa_cli -i $interface scan_results | awk 'NR>1 {OFS="\n>>"; print $NF}')
            echo "results: $scan_res" >> $logfile
            echo $scan_res
            ;;
        "FAIL")
            echo "FAILED TO SCAN" >> $logfile
            echo "FAILED TO SCAN"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "ERROR: empty or undefined event for $interface" >> $logfile
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac

}

echo "return: $(scan_wifi)" >> $logfile
echo "" >> $logfile
echo "" >> $logfile
```

`function.sh` locates in my `$HOME` directory. I also have a file `/usr/local/bin/networkmenu` containing the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

bash /home/speklap/function.sh
```

Until now everything is ok. I've added the `/user/local/bin/networkmenu` to the sudoers file to execute without password.

```
speklap ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/networkmenu
```

In the terminal as user:

```
$ networkmenu
```

`.logfile`:

```
function

scan: OK
Scanning wifi
results: thuis
return: thuis
```

But when executing with a shortcut through i3, it doesn't work.

`.config/i3/config`:

```
bindsym $mod+n exec networkmenu
```

Results in a `.logfile`:

```
function

scan: 
ERROR: empty or undefined event for wlp2s0
return:
```

Why is that, why can't i3 invoke the script like I can in the terminal? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: if someone can come up with a better title, feel free to change. I had no clue on how to google this and my results were poorly and a lot of false positives

EDIT: outputting to `/tmp/nm.log` as per comment of @cas

```
+ logfile=//home/speklap/.logfile
+ echo functions
+ echo ''
+ interface=wlp2s0
++ scan_wifi
+++ sudo wpa_cli -i wlp2s0 scan
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
++ scan=
++ echo 'scan: '
++ case "$scan" in
++ echo 'ERROR: empty or undefined event for wlp2s0'
++ exit 1
+ echo 'return: '
+ echo ''
+ echo ''
```

So now we know what the problem is, `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`
I can fix this by adding `wpa_cli` to the sudoers file? Or is there a better solution. As in changing `networkmenu` to `sudo bash /$HOME/function.sh`?

Comment: "I've added the /user/local/bin/networkmenu to the sudoers file to execute without password" ... But you're not executing `networkmenu` with sudo. You're executing `wpa_cli` with sudo

Comment: my guess is that i3 was run in an environment before your custom PATH was set, so doesn't have the sbin directories in $PATH.   Try logging what happens in the script.  e.g. change your `networkmenu` script to have something like `bash -x /home/speklap/function.sh >/tmp/nm.log 2>&1`, and then examine `/tmp/nm.log`.

Comment: @muru my understanding of it was that if running a script with sudo rights, all calls to sudo will be executed since the script is running with elevated permissions. And I'm wrong I see now, problem was that I executed the script in the timeout of asking for sudo password in the terminal so it seemed it worked by putting it in the sudoers file.

Comment: @cas thanks for that. Interesting way to debug script files.

Comment: `set -x` in a script or `bash -x` when running it are both standard shell script debugging methods (well, one method with two different ways of invoking it).

Comment: looks like you need to use `sudo`'s `-A` option, or set the `SUDO_ASKPASS` variable.   see `man sudo`.

Comment: BTW, if you run a script with `sudo` then you don't need to run individual commands in the script with sudo - it's already running as root.   Also, adding a script name to the sudoers file doesn't mean it will always run as root.  It means that the specified users or group are **allowed** to run that script as root.  NOPASSWD means they're allowed to do it AND they don't have to enter their password.   to run it as root, it has to be invoked as `sudo /usr/local/bin/networkmenu`

Comment: But you *aren't* running the script with sudo, at least not anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `sudo` defintion is wrong. You've allowed `networkmenu` to run with `sudo`, but you actually use `networkmenu` instead of `sudo networkmenu`, so it is given no additional privileges to run. (Simply putting an entry into the `sudoers` file doesn't grant that application any additional privileges; rather, it allows the `sudo` command to provide those defined priviledges for the named application.)

The only place you are using `sudo` in your script is for `sudo wpa_cli ...`, so either you need to run your entire script under `sudo` or you need to allow `wpa_cli` to be called from `sudo`.

Option 1: Allow the entire script to run with root privileges

- No change to the `sudo` entry
- Explicitly set the `PATH` at the top of your script, because it'll be running as root
- Remove all instances of `sudo` from in your script
- Call the tool as `sudo networkmenu` instead of just `networkmenu`

Option 2: Allow the script to run as the unprivileged user, but permit elevation for the `wpa_cli` command:

- Change the `sudo` entry

  ```
  speklap ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/wpa_cli *
  ```
- Explicitly set the `PATH` at the top of your script, because `wpa_cli` is in a directory that is often omitted from users' `PATH` settings (`/sbin`)

Comment: Thanks your for the elaborate answer with different options. I just had option 1 working. I came back to comment that I indeed had the privileges of `sudo` mixed up and your answer popped up.